# Can I move a webform to another drupal installation?

Tags: 6, webforms, migrations, importing-exporting

I have created a few webforms on our development server and would like to move them over to a production installation. Can I do this with node export?

I'm not concerned with migrate any user responses (as we were only testing).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You didn't say what version you are using but if it is drupal 6, there is a module for that exact purpose.

http://drupal.org/project/webform_share

Edit: Since posting this, the module has been updated with a Drupal 7 branch as well.

Comment: I am using Drupal 6 and you may have made my Monday morning a bit easier. I'll give this a go and report back. Thank you!

Comment: Yep. Thank you this did the trick. We can design and test on our development server, and on approval, move the form over to the production box.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not familiar with webform_share, but I have had good experience with a module called [Node Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_export), which works pretty well with webforms, and notably with webforms where the form is integrated with CiviCRM via the [webform_civicrm integration](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm) module.

Comment: You may find that you will need to open the CiviCRM tab, and reset some settings such as number of contacts, number of telephones etc, but once done you don't need to also reselect all the fields or phone types etc, they should just reappear once you save.